# Qt C++ QMYSQL driver not loaded on MacOS - Tutorial for building QMYSQL Plugin

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I just spent a day figuring out how to build the drivers for MySQL support in a Qt-Application, because the explanation given in the [Qt-documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html) was not clear enough for me (even misleading, actually) so I thought I'd share the steps that worked for me.

I did this on MacOS 10.15.3, with mysql 8.0.19 and Qt 5.14.1.

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably need to install mysql. I ran these three commands, not sure if all of them are necessary:

```
brew install mysql
brew install mysql-client
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

This installed mysql into `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19` and the client into `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.18`.

After installing the client, my terminal prompted me to set compiler flags:

```
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/include"
```

So I added these two lines to my .bash_profile-file. (This file sets environment variables every time you open a terminal. You can edit it by simply navigating to your home directory (`cd ~`) and typing `vim .bash_profile`.)

I also added the mysql and mysql-client paths to the PATH-variable by adding these two lines to the .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.18
```

And while we're at it, I also added the path to Qt's qmake-tool:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/USERNAME/Qt/5.14.1/clang_64/bin (replace USERNAME with your username)
```

Now we're all set up. Navigate to the sqldrivers-folder in your Qt-installation, for me that's `/Users/USERNAME/Qt/5.14.1/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers`. (btw, installing Qt via brew didn't work for me, I had to download the installer from their website.)

In that folder, you need to run qmake with the full path to your mysql-dylib-files, like so:

`qmake -- MYSQL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/lib`

(note how this is different from the Qt-documentation, where they tell you that the prefix is /usr/local - this is why I called it misleading.)
Then, still in the sqldrivers-folder, run `make`. Then, navigate into the mysql-subfolder (`cd mysql`) and run `make install`. I was then able to compile and run my project.

Comment: Sorry but the prefix path depends heavily on where you install your packages. And it is clearly stated that you have to find this out by yourself: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#building-the-drivers

Comment: You're right, it says so in the documentation, but later on they specifically describe the process for MacOS / Linux systems and use the prefix /usr/local in their example. If you only copy and paste that, it won't work. To me, it wasn't immediately clear where I needed to point the prefix, and it wasn't clear to me which files are the required dylibs. Having one more explanation that might help someone can't hurt.